# How to upload an image

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

HI, I am using asp as server side script. I am calling asp page from java by HttpURLConnection and passing the image by ImageIO.write() method. can any body tell me how can I upload that file from asp into my server directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pure (no DLL) upload, you should look at a [Pure ASP Upload](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pure-asp-upload.htm) or [check out this article](http://www.asp101.com/articles/jacob/scriptupload.asp)

But, a more common, tested, with better performance solution is installing a third party library.
I like [AbcUpload from WebSuperGoo](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcupload-1.htm) (free with LinkBack license)

### basicupload.htm

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="basicupload.asp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="filefield"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

### basicupload.asp

```
<% @Language="VBScript" %>
<%
Set theForm = Server.CreateObject("ABCUpload4.XForm")
theForm.Overwrite = True
If theForm.Files("filefield").FileExists Then
   theForm.Files("filefield").Save "myupload.dat"
End If
%>
<html>
<body>
File uploaded...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can to tell me some code for classic asp such that which can upload files without knowing there name. like in php we have  $_FILES which holds all the files uploaded

Comment: there's a good chance that you can use a "for f in theForm.Files" loop in the above example.